# Find element with attribute - SimpleXML xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm trying to select an element from my xml with a particular attribute 'id'.
This is my xml:

```
<listitems>
  <item id="1">
    <name>item 1</name>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <name>item 2</name>
  </item>
  <item id="3">
    <name>item 3</name>
  </item>
</listitems>
```

This the php file:

```
<?php
$simplexml = simplexml_file_load('test.xml');
$item = $simplexml->xpath('item[@id="1"]');
?>
```

Then if I try, for example:

```
<?php $item->addchild('description','textdescription'); ?>
```

I get on the last line this error:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function addchild() on a non-object"

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I don't know SimpleXML, so this isn't an answer. However, I'll bet that its default behavior (consistent with XSLT) is to return the string value of the XPath, in this case "item 1". I suspect there's another function to return a NODELIST.

Comment: Actually it's the opposite. SimpleXML xpath always returns `SimpleXMLElement` (an element list), no matter the actual value of the xpath expression.

Comment: It's `simplexml_load_file` not `simplexml_file_load`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function of a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=call+to+a+member+function+of+a+non+object)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SimpleXML's xpath() always returns an array of elements, even when you specify it by id. To add something to it, you'll need to extract the specific element out of that array.

Try this:

```
$items = $simplexml->xpath('item[@id="1"]');
$item = $items[0];
$item->addchild('description','textdescription');
```

Or better yet, verify that you actually found something with that id:

```
$items = $simplexml->xpath('item[@id="1"]');
if (count($items) == 1)
{
    $item = $items[0];
    $item->addchild('description','textdescription');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the xpath is not aware that "id" is a unique attribute in this case, as with other attributes that xpath would be non-unique. Try:

```
<?php $item[0]->addchild('description','textdescription'); ?>
```

to select the first returned child in the array.